# Time it takes to unroll a spool at a fixed RPM

Tags: calculus

I would like to know how to calculate the time it takes to unroll a roll at a fixed RPM

Variables:  Thickness of material - .125", RPM - 2000 RPM, Starting diameter - 10", Finish diameter - 3.3"

Application is a veneer lathe that peels logs into veneer that makes plywood.

Much appreciated
/D

Answer (score 1):

If you shave off a thickness of $1/8$" then each revolution you'll take $1/4$" off of the diameter.

This will take $4\times(10-3.3) = 27$ revolutions (rounding up) to shave off everything. This takes $27/2000$ minutes or about $0.81$ seconds.

Comment: Thanks John, you make it look so simple.  One thought though if the material is .125" and you take one wrap off should the equation be 4 X (10-3.3)?

Comment: Daryl you're absolutely right. The diameter goes down $1/4$" each revolution not $1/8$". I'm glad it was helpful and that you understood the solution well enough to point out my error! I edited my answer.

Comment: Perfect thanks John